# Pyspark: reading multiple JSON files from path

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to read 20 JSON files from a path and create a dataframe, but even though the schema gets created, the df only contains null values ("Query returned no results"). Here is my code:

```
ordersJsonPath = "dbfs:/user/xyz/dbacademy/raw/orders/stream" 
ordersDF = spark.read.schema(userDefinedSchema).json(ordersJsonPath)
```

When I run the code with a specific JSON file, it works.

```
"dbfs:/user/xyz/dbacademy/raw/orders/stream/order_0612a18b-0cc7-43ea-9f5b-155aad967cb9_2020-01-01.json"
```

From what I understood, I need to create a schema manually when working with JSON or am I confusing things here and a manual schema is obsolete when working with multiple files?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I checked the schema of the first 5 files in the path, they are  all the same and they can all be read by the query I wrote (not streamed though, as this requires to give the whole path as input). When I start the readStream query, not even these first 5 JSON files get processed. Just nothing happens:
[image]

Another edit: I got it solved, needed to add /* to the path ...

Comment: Did you ensure the schema of all files are same? Normally this happens when you have schema discrepancy. Its not mandatory to provide schema, but if you want your data should be inferred correctly to correct data format that you want then you can provide schema

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks for your reply. This is for some databricks certification that I am doing and the path with the files was actually given to me as part of the instructions. It is especially weird, that I just started to stream (read & write) the query and the first file "accidently" got written in the target table. But when I run the code again, nothing happens.

Comment: When I leave the uderDefinedSchema away, I am getting an error message: "Unable to infer schema for JSON at . It must be specified manually;"

Comment: also try `json(<your path>, multiLine=True)`. And above error shows your files have different schema.

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks again for your help. I added some more info to my initial post, after I checked the schemas of the files in the path (at least the first 5)

Answer (score 0):

got it solved, needed to add /* to the path ...